Some Options log4j2 in opensearch do not work
I'm trying to configure log4j2 for opensearch 2.15.
To configure I use the log4j2.properties file with the following configuration:
status = error
monitorInterval = 1

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = console
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c{1.}] [%node_name]%marker %m%n

######## Server JSON ############################
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = rolling
appender.rolling.fileName = ${sys:opensearch.logs.base_path}${sys:file.separator}${sys:opensearch.logs.cluster_name}_server.json
appender.rolling.filePermissions = rw-r-----
appender.rolling.layout.type = OpenSearchJsonLayout
appender.rolling.layout.type_name = server
appender.rolling.filePattern = ${sys:opensearch.logs.base_path}${sys:file.separator}${sys:opensearch.logs.cluster_name}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.json.gz
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size = 128MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.fileIndex = nomax
appender.rolling.strategy.action.type = Delete
appender.rolling.strategy.action.basepath = ${sys:opensearch.logs.base_path}
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.type = IfFileName
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.glob = ${sys:opensearch.logs.cluster_name}-*
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.nested_condition.type = IfLastModified
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.nested_condition.age = 60D

At the same time, opensearch log files are archived, but cannot be deleted after 60 days.
And the option to automatically re-read log4j2 does not work. I have to constantly restart opensearch.
Can you tell me what I did wrong?
I tried different settings, but none of them gave the desired effect.
